# where is the plugins folder of xcode 6.1

Tags: xcode, plugins

Where can I find the plugins folder for Xcode 6.1?

Recently, I installed the dash app in my mac, here is the link: https://github.com/omz/Dash-Plugin-for-Xcode
But I don't really like it, then I try to uninstall it. Then I found that the link given from the link above doesn't work for my xcode. My xcode version is 6.1, and operating system is Yosemite GM. So where can I find the plugins folder of xcode, then I can remove this plugins?
Thanks guys.

Comment: I've tried putting an .xcplugin in two different locations:

`~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins`

and in

`~/Library/Application Support/Xcode/Plug-ins`
The first location gets it working in Xcode 5. Neither one gets it working for Xcode 6.

(Related: Is there a settings option that dictates which folder is used for plugins? Maybe I can just look there...)

Comment: "~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins" works fine for me in Xcode 6.1. Notice that it's ~/Library/, which is not the same as /Library/

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the `~`. I installed it under my user's home directory, not under the root. Installing in this folder makes the plugin work for Xcode 5, but not for Xcode 6. Removing the plugin from this same folder disables it from Xcode 5 (as it should)...actually, I'm going to try rebooting.

Comment: Assuming you are dropping your plugin into the correct directory and still are unable to get it to work...try grabbing the source and rebuilding. That finally got it working for me.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this @WindMemory?

Answer (score 36):

I was able to install and build the Dash plugin for Xcode 6.1 / Yosemite, and it installed correctly in `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins`. Notice that it begins with ~, the /Library/ folder is *not* the correct one.

Comment: @AnthonyC It works for me, which to me makes it rather definitive that it's the right location. You must certainly be doing something *else* wrong. Try the Dash plugin as a example, it's very easy to confirm it's working.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much Claus. I am aware that there is something else that is wrong. This plugin is working for Xcode 5, but not 6 on the same machine. So yes, something else is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I have Xcode 6.1.1, here's what I did and it worked.

1. Right click on plugin file > **Show Package Contents**
2. Find and edit the **Info.plist** file.
3. In **DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs** add the key C4A681B0-4A26-480E-93EC-1218098B9AA0

Save your Info.plist file.

Then go to */Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns* folder, and copy your plugin file there (the administrator password will be required).

You can now launch Xcode and use your plugins ;-)

Comment: This works for me and Xcode 6. Old plugins need to be updated with the new key. However, the plugin doesn't need to be copied to the Xcode.app. They can stay in `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins`.

Answer (score -3):

It should be here `~/Library/Application Support/Xcode/Plug-ins`.