# xcode crashes when I try to open any project

Tags: xcode

xcode crashes when I am trying to open any project (.xcodeproj) file. The crash report saying

> **Xcode quit unexpectedly while using the libJP2.dylib plug-in**

Here is the more details

> Process:         Xcode [733]
>
> Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
>
> Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
>
> Version:         6.0.1 (6528)
>
> Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-6528000000000000~2
>
> App Item ID:     497799835
>
> App External ID: 712682811
>
> Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
>
> Parent Process:  launchd [161]
>
> Responsible:     Xcode [733]
>
> User ID:         506
>
> PlugIn Path:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJP2.dylib
>
> PlugIn Identifier: libJP2.dylib
>
> PlugIn Version:    ??? (1044)
>
> Date/Time:       2015-05-08 10:34:45.103 +0530
>
> OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
>
> Report Version:  11
>
> Anonymous UUID:  57F21D56-D9B6-5A40-6209-07ECF66DD709
>
> Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)
>
> Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000032, 0x00007fff764f5018

would anybody please help me ?

Comment: Did you install the plugin mentioned in the crash? If so, try uninstalling it.

Comment: how do I do that ? I did not find the plugin on the net and could you please tell me how to find it on the mac ?

Comment: You could try removing the plugin from XCode - [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444600/where-is-the-plugins-folder-of-xcode-6-1) might help you find that.

Comment: Try to check import statements of .h file. If you import .m file instead of .h. This error comes up. :